# Insert a slash in a string after every number except at the end (PHP)

Tags: php, string, insert, slash

i've a string

```
$string;
```

in this string i have a number, like `3743687`

i wish to add a slash after every number, except at the end, so the result will be

`3/7/4/3/6/8/7`

is there a php function to do this, right ? any advice ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = '3743687';

$newString = implode('/',str_split($string));

var_dump($newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "3743687";

$string = implode("/", str_split($string));

echo $string;
```